# span text length of column (or li)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

I have a mouseover function that changes the background-color of the span of an li element, but the background-color change only changes the background of the span text and not the entire length column. How can I extend the background-color to the entire length of the column without changing the li element's background-color. I do not want to change the li element's background-color because the li element may contain children ul and li elements who's background color I do not want to change.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8d965kbd/

HTML:

```
<li>
  <span class="text">HIGHLIGHT FULL LENGTH (DO NOT HIGHTLIGHT WITH BELOW HIGHTLIGHT)</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <span class="text">HIGHLIGHT FULL LENGTH (DO NOT HIGHTLIGHT WITH ABOVE HIGHTLIGHT)</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
      $(document).on({
              mouseenter: function () {
                      $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
              },
              mouseleave: function () {
                      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
              }
      }, ".text");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/vtoe5eqx/1/

```
display:inline-block; //add it to the text class
```

Comment: inline-block will not work for this if the span is shorter than one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:block;` onto the span.

https://jsfiddle.net/8d965kbd/3/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<span>` use `<div>` instead, the reason is that `<span>` is just an inline-block element while `<div>` is a block element.
Meaning `<span>` width is default to `auto` which will only base its width on the content while `<div>` will set its width to `100%` regardless of the content, that's why when you apply a `background-color` change for `<span>`, it only fills up only by its width.

Update: You can also use other block elements as an alternative aside from `<div>` such as `<p>` `<h1> ~ <h6>`